# Typing instructor on FB Messenger postback button is being automatically added after request is finished

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My bot is replying to users with a message that includes a postback button. Once the user clicks on a button, he is being replied with the next sequence of messages.

For some reason, an automatically typing instructor is being shown after all the messages are sent.

Sometimes it will be shown for the whole 20 seconds it can, sometimes just for a second and sometimes none at all.

The server is returning to FB an `200 ok status`.

I tried to send a `typing_off` message at the end of the process and to send 200 response before the request is being finished, didn't help.

Any idea how to solve it or what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you sending response with 200 right back when you receive message?